# Can a train with magnets attached move with less fuel?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

For a train, if we attach magnets ( big ones ) such that, for each compartment north faces front and south faces back, can that train move.[image: the train looks like this.]

So if this is right, we can move a train by just moving the first compartment of the train, more likely the fuel consumption is reduced by a large amount.

Comment: Try googling "maglev".  This will tell you that magnets can provide motive force, but in order to do so, some magnets must be stationary, and some must be affixed to the moving vehicle.  In your diagram, there is no stationary magnet to attract or repel the moving magnets or to create a magnetic field in which the train may move.  This may be helpful: http://www.eduplace.com/science/hmxs/ps/mode2/cricket/sect7cc.shtml

Comment: In your diagram, each N/S pair will attract each other until they make contact (you can do this with a pair of refrigerator magnets). At this point they stick to each other and might as well be nailed together or held by standard car couplers. How does this save energy? When you move the first car you have to move the others, just like you would in a regular train.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I mean, when we move the first car, the second car would indeed be attracted to the first (as you said,to get nailed to each other) and so on they go, so I thought that all of them move, won't they?

Comment: Yes, all of them move, and by the same amount as in a regular train, so it will take the same amount of energy. It doesn't matter if the cars are attached with couplers, ropes, superglue...

Comment: Look at it this way. If each car weighs 100 pounds, and you lift one up until all three are hanging in line - do you expect to feel 100 pounds or 300 pounds of weight? Same principle applies to moving them horizontally.

Comment: You can already buy toy trains where the carriages are held together by magnets if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is exactly equivalent to the train moving using normal couplers.

Note that the force required to move the train is the same ( depending on the mass of the train and the co-efficient of friction between the train and track ).
Therefore, the amount of energy required to move the train is the same and hence the amount of fuel required is also the same.

A way to reduce the fuel will be to reduce the coefficient of friction by fixing opposite polarity magnets on the bottom of the train and track. [ a super-crude maglev]